# Getting started with SQLite on windows, why isn't it outputting anything?

Tags: sqlite, windows-7

I've just started using SQLite, following the tutorials [here](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex0.html) and I'm using this on windows. I've got sqlite3.exe extracted to a folder on my desktop, and am running the following line in a command prompt to test it:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

which the official documentation claims should create a file called test.db to work with. However, it doesn't appear to be doing anything, no files are created and it gives no errors or success messages, just another `sqlite>` prompt. Am I missing something to get this working on windows 7? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database file does not exist, SQLite starts with an empty database.

The file itself will not be created until you actually write to the database.
Try creating something:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(some stuff);
```

Comment: There we go, not sure why that didn't work initially. Thanks!